# DNS intermittent failure, including internet, intranet and docker-compose network

Tags: dns

I have a VPS `(Ubuntu 16.04)` and deploy a website with `docker-compose`, and it worked fine before.

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    restart: always
    command: uwsgi --ini /opt/workspace/backend/uwsgi.ini
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    expose:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes

volumes:
  redis-data:
```

However, recently, it suffers DNS intermittent failure (every 2-3 days).

1. `MySQL Client` raise error:

`Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.com` (it's in internet)

2. `Redis Client` raise error:

`ConnectionError: Error -3 connecting to redis:6379. Temporary failure in name resolution.`

3. When the problem happens, `ping` vps's ip is ok. But `ssh` is not.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a DNS issue, check the logs on your server, the server might be too busy to answer at any given point in time. There can be multiple reasons for server being busy. Eg. it could be made busy by bots, or some other process might be running.
And since you have publicly open mysql port, it will be the culprit mostly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have found the problem: memory usage too high -> using disk swap -> DNS failure